# stream_in part of .json file

Tags: json, r

I have a large .json file and I only want to read in a part of it.

I tried the the following solutions but they didn´t work:

```
yelp <- stream_in(file("yelp_academic_dataset_review.json"), paigesize = 500)
yelp <- stream_in(file("yelp_academic_dataset_review.json"), nrows = 500)
```

Anyone know how it works?

Comment: Are you saying you only want to read in the first 500 rows?

Comment: FYI- the `pagesize` argument you have doesn't mean 'read in the first 500 rows'. What it's doing is setting each page to 500 rows, then reading in all pages and flattening them. You can see that in the `jsonlite` documentation. `pagesize`: the "number of lines to read/write from/to the connection per iteration". Iteration referring to page. What you need to find is a way to essentially 'break' the function after the first page is read in.

Answer (score 1):

First off- always helpful to provide the packages you are using, in your case `jsonlite`.

One solution is parsing the data file (as a .txt file) prior to streaming it in.

```
yelp <- readLines("yelp_academic_dataset_review.json")[1:500]
yelp <- stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", yelp)))
```

I'm assuming your file is local?

Answer (score -2):

I have had success with actual piping/streaming json in the past. Ie, from the command line,

```
cat x.json | parse_json.py
```

Then you write your python script:

```
import json,sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    js_line = json.loads(line.rstrip())
    try:
        # do something with js_line['x']['y']
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

I'm not sure why you want to use stream_in, but this somewhat manual approach can be effective

Comment: This question is tagged `R`, not python.

Answer (score -2):

I use this code for extracting 1400001 to 1450000 lines of yelp:

```
setwd("d:/yelp_dataset")
rm(list=ls())
library(jsonlite)
rev<- 'd:/yelp_dataset/review.JSON'
revu<-jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(readLines(rev)[1400001:1450000],verbose=F)
```